# How to write a C++ boolean function which uses n times the ternary condition statement?

Tags: c++, boolean, ternary-operator

I have a very simple question by I am very confused by the way I could implement this. I want to create a Boolean variable in a single line composed of ternary statement such as this:

boolean = a ? b : (c ? d : (e ? f : (g ? i : j );

It is working for 1, 2 or 3 such imbricate conditions for the purposes of my codes but I which to write it in a way that I could choose how many such ternary conditions I want to put into each other to define the Boolean variable.

And I am stuck with this because at the end it looks like I cannot add the last condition. I have tried to think of a recursive function, maybe with some counter, but I could not manage to write it. I do not know if what I ask is simpler or clear.

The condition are not fully independent of each other, there are intervals (coordinates in space) that follow each other somehow. So for example the 'a' in my example would be something like 11 and then it would continue when it is false with a new condition saying 22 and so on. Hence my idea of introducing some counter to put into the conditions.

But when I arrive at the last false condition, I don't know what to do because I cannot set up a random z>something to make my code work.

I am trying something like:

```
bool f(double x, double value, double z, double d, double n, double step, int &count);{
         bool result;
         count++;
         if (count == n) {return result}
         result = (x >=value+count*step  && x<value+(count+1)*step) ? z>=d : f(x,value,z,d,n,step, &count);
   }
```

So of course, besides probably many mistakes in the way I am writing recursive function since I never use them and do not use C or C++ usually, it will appear that in the last call of the function by itself, we will have something like a ? b : without the last parameter if the statement is false.

I tried to be as clear as I could. You can ask questions if you do not get the point. And any help is welcome, recursive functions, normal functions or a way to do it with no function at all...

Best regards and thanks in advance for your answers!

Edit:

The code with if should be something like:

```
if (a){
    b}
else{
    if (c){
        d}
    else{
        if(e){
           f}
        else{
           if(g){
              I}
           else{
              j}
```

I may have forgotten some bracket but I hope it is understandable. And this point is to continue with, say n, if statements like this in a single line to create a Boolean variable and then being able to choose n instead of rewriting a new code each time I want to add an if statement.

EDIT about recursion:

Can someone explains me why this kind of function creates an infinite loop?

```
bool f(double x, double l, double z, double d,  double step, int &count){
         int  n = (int)l/step;\\number of steps
         count++;
         if (count <  n)
                return  (x >=l+count*step  && x<l+(count+1)*step) ? z>=d*count : f(x,l,z,d,step,count);

         else               
                return z>=d*(count-1);
   }
```

I set the counter 'count' to -1 before calling the function and it seems to be the problem. It does the loop correctly but then it restarts again and again so that I cannot even check if my code makes any sense for my purpose. I thought after each return calling the function recursively, it would increase the counter but once it reaches n, it should return something else and go out of the function, not restart the counter and doing everything again...

Comment: When you wrote the code out in a nice verbose **readable** `if`, `else if` branch list, what did it look like?

Comment: @Amentia Using ternary conditional statements in behalf of _"efficiency"_ and _"elegance"_ is way overrated. Just use good old `if / else` constructs instead. Besides better readability,  those will give you best capabilities for debugging the code as a benefit on top.

Comment: ternary looses its benefit (expressiveness for short if-else) already with a second condition. It may be a nice exercise but in the end all you get is an obfuscated if-else

Comment: Why would you *want* to write unreadable code like that?

Comment: You can answer my question by considering normal if statements instead of the ternary ones. The point is I don't want my code to be elegant or readable but efficient. And the requirement is to create a geometrical shape by returning a single Boolean variable. For a sphere it would be something like x2+y2+z2 < r2. But my shape is more complicated and I don't see how to use if statements that would in the end create a single Boolean variable like the one from the sphere. On the other hand I tested my ugly ternary conditions and it did what I wanted for a particular case that I want to generalise

Comment: @Amentia Your unreadable code is *not* going to be more efficient. After it has been through the compilers optimizer, most likely the same comes out as the readable version.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl. I understand that what you say is a very general principle of coding. But I should explain in more detail what is my problem maybe so that you can suggest something. Imagine you have a huge cube filled with points at each integer coordinate for example. The code I want to write is suppose to return a single boolean that represents a shape that I dig into this big square. And I don't see a way to do it differently than with a single line. In my case, you can see it is some kind of steps that I will combine with another shape at the end. But imagine you want half a sphere:

Comment: In this case I would write : return x2+y2+z2 < r2 && z > 0; or something similar. I do not see how it can be done in several steps rather than in a single line. I have also looked at some similar codes to create these shapes and I could not find a single one that is doing the job in another way than a return with a single line defining a boolean representing the shape. But I would be glad to know if there is a way.

Answer (score 1):

To write that `if ... else if` ladder more clearly, get rid of the brackets and get rid of the indentation. Like this:

```
if (a)
    boolean = b;
else if (c)
    boolean = d;
```

and so on. But I’d be inclined to write it as a function:

```
if (a)
    return b;
else if (c)
    return d;
```

and so on. Still, if you like the ternary operator, it can be written in a disciplined way that is easily read:

```
boolean = a ? b
    : c ? d
    : e ? f
    : g;
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip on how to write this in a more readable way.

Answer (score 1):

[4th version of the answer, taking into account comments]

In the particular case of the first simple example provided, it is possible to write a variadic function. Here the template ...args parameter indicates a variable number of parameters. One can call f(false,false,true) or f(false,false,false,true,true) or more parameters.

```
bool ff(bool a, bool b, bool c) {
    return a ? b : c;
}
template<class ...Args>
bool ff(bool a, bool b, Args ...args){
    return a ? b : ff(args...);
}
```

As user463035818 mentioned, there is a risk of short-circuiting in this first call of ff(.) function (by main), when all booleans are likely to be evaluated during this fist call. I don't know what would really happen with optimization by the compiler, with possible inlining and unrolling, but it is useless to stress the compiler.

Anyway I now understand that the number of steps is an input parameter, and a variadic template function does not seem to be applicable. It is certainly possible to solve it with a recursive function, similar to the one you proposed. However, in my opinion, a simple 'for loop' will be both efficient and flexible.
In my previous answer, I proposed a solution based on a for loop. However, as it does not correspond to your needs, because I misunderstood the mathematical problem, I removed it.

Instead, I come back to the second recursive function that you proposed in your post. You asked why the recursion did not finish. I could not comment it directly because of my poor reputation. As I did not see why the programme did not stop, I implemented it and the programme finished normally, but with a result that does not seem correct. I see a problem about parameter *l*. It seems to correspond both to a range for *x* and to a minimal value for *x*. I tried to correct it. It may happen that I did not select the input parameter values correctly . Therefore, I put the corresponding program hereafter for you to be able to check it.

```
#include    <iostream>

   bool f(double x, double xmin, double range, double z, double d,  double step, int &count){
         int  n = range/step;   //number of steps
         count++;
         if (count <  n) {
             double a = xmin + count*step;
             return  ((x >=a)  && (x< a + step)) ? z>=d*count : f(x,xmin,range,z,d,step,count);
        } else               
             return z>=d*(count-1);
   }

  int main () {
      int count = -1;
      double xmin = 0.0;
      double x = 2.0;
      double range = 4.0;
      double step = 1.0;
      double d = 1.0;
      double z = 2.0;
      bool test = f (x, xmin, range, z, d, step, count);
      std::cout << "test = " << test << "\n";
      std::cout << "count = " << count << "\n";
      return 0;
  }
```

In this particular case, it would be better to replace *range* by *n* as input parameter, to avoid redundant calculation of *n*.

Comment: So it means that instead of the plane  (x+y+z >=0) which represents a flat basis for the tetrahedron, I would like to replace the equation with one that create little steps all spaced equally. Maybe it is now clear what I want to do. And I succeeded in making some fixed number of steps but not a general one that can be entered as an input.

Comment: I have to read again your answer and some other to get a better understanding of what you are trying to explain to me about the use of functions. It is a bit late in my timezone but I wanted to provide an example that is a simplified version of what I am doing. In this case I create a tetrahedron oriented along the diagonal of a cube with this boolean variable: return (x+y+z >= 0) & (-x+y+z <= c1) & (x-y+z <= c1) & (x+y-z <= c1) ; where c1 is some number that allows me to intersect 4 planes so that the correct tetrahedron is created by taking every point that is inside the defined equations.

Comment: And sorry, the second message should be read before the first one, I had a problem with the edit function and had to rewrite it.

Comment: I focused on the simplified version and was thinking on variadic templates. Now I understand that the number of steps is an input parameter. I will edit my answer and propose another solution. (We are in the same timezone).

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. I am trying to use your idea for my code but I am still not there yet. The fact is that I do not understand very well what you write. For instance, when you have in the beginning "if (t0 < 0) return false;", for me it means that the functions stops here and does not create the shape. I thought a return statement was always the end of a function except an recursive one. So if this is a simple task for you, could you update a second time your message with an equivalent recursive function so that I can compare the two? It would be great.

Comment: how does this not loose short-circuiting? When I call `ff( some_condition, some_other_condition, some_other_condition2)`, then all the conditions have to be evaluated to call the function

Comment: Is what you call short-circuiting the fact that when something is False or True the function ends and return the value?

Comment: @user463035818 You are right. Sorry I misunderstood what you meant by short-circuiting. I wanted to mention that there is no short-circuiting inside ff(.) function. But I corrected the answer. Please check.

Comment: @Amentia I assume that you want to detect points at figure borders. Which values are used for inputs c and step? I understand that sequences c(i) test (i) will be generated. What will look like test(i) sequence? Is it (t,t,t,f,f,f) or (f,f,t,t,f)? I first assumed first case. Your comment seems to indicate that it could be 2nd one instead. I slightly corrected the function fff() accordingly. I will try to provide an equivalent recursive solution tomorrow.

Comment: Hi I do not understand  the line template<class ...Args>. What is it aimed at? The value of c is not that important and I don't have it now, I calculated it mathematically but I can simplifiy more my example because I see I am confusing people. We could also imagine creating a square in 2D with equations such as -y<-4 && y > 4 && -x<-4 &&x>4. Assuming the origine is in the middle of the square. Now my steps are supposed to replace the part where -4<x<-2 by a new value for the minimum of x. So that it makes like a stair instead of a flat line at the bottom. Which means step is an input paramter

Comment: Maybe I am not clear but I am too tired sorry. But I really appreciate your help. Step is a length so there could be theoretically as many as we want to if we could write a general code.

________
|              |          
|         __|
|    __|  
|__|

Comment: Sorry just imagine a reversed stairs with variable steps, with is what I want to replace my flat basis for the tetrahedron, the square or whatever would be a simple exmaple to give me

Comment: @Amentia I modified the answer to explain the 'Args' a little bit. You will have more details by searching for 'variadic template' on internet. I also tried to answer the last question in your post, about the function that did not end. I still need to better understand the exact result that you want to get.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the updates! I upvoted your comment but apparently I am not an important person on the website so it will not appear. After looking at your recursive code and at the fact that you said it was working, I looked more carefully and saw that my calculation was simply huge. I was not in an infinite loop, only a very long one, and after some thinking on the parameters, I could get what I wanted. I just made as many steps as possible since I was unsure of my last condition and it worked. That is because the "stairs" are then cut by whatever shape I add.

Comment: I think it is dirty but it works for the first calculations I wanted to perform. I don't know if I should answer my own question and say that the problem is solved because I think there is room for improvement and I saw many people do not agree with this kind of code. So perhaps I will come back with an optimisation later. But anyway thanks to all and Damien in particular for helping me.

Comment: @Amentia Thank you Amentia for letting us informed that you finally succeded. You are not allowed to upvote (I am not allowed too !) but if you think that an answer has helped you, you can "accept" it, even if it is not a final and complete solution. At least it is what I understand concerning functionning of this site.

Answer (score 0):

**Readability vs efficiency**

> The point is I don't want my code to be elegant or readable but efficient.

Honestly, I think this is not a good strategy. Inefficient code is not elegant. This does of course not imply that readable code is automatically efficient. 
However, it is much easier to accidentally prevent the compiler doing an optimization rather than pushing it to emit better code than it already does anyhow. Readable code does contain less errors and helps you to avoid obvious inefficiencies. That being said,...

**Why not to write a variadic conditional function?**

Besides readability there is one more thing to consider: short-circuiting. With the plain conditional

```
bool x = condition ? t : some_other_function_call();
```

in case `condition` is `true`, then `some_other_function_call()` will not be evaluated, while in

```
bool x = foo(t,some_other_function_call());
```

the other function will be called in either case. You cannot get short-circuiting with `foo`.

**What to do instead?**

The answer by Pete Becker nicely demonstrates how to write the conditions in a clean way (most importantly you don't need to nest the cases when they are mutually exclusive (they are for the ternary!)).

**Anyhow... how could a variadic conditional function be written?**

Just for the sake of completeness, this is how you could write such a function to replace `bool x = a ? b : (c ? d : (e ? f : (g ? i : j );` with a funciton call (please dont):

```
// DISCLAIMER: DONT DO THIS
bool my_conditional(std::vector<bool> x){
    if (x.size() == 1) return *x.begin();
    bool condition = *x.begin();
    bool true_value = *(x.begin()+1);
    return condition ? true_value : my_ternary({x.begin()+2,x.end()});
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
my_conditional({ condition1, true_value1, condition2, true_value2, false_value});
```

eg

```
std::cout << my_conditional({false,false,false,false,false});
```

prints `0`.

Comment: Hello, sorry for not replying earlier to your message, but I am having a hard time trying to get what you want to convey. I have never heard of variadic conditional before and I am not sure whether what you propose is a nice way to solve my problem or not. Could you develop more what your function called "my_conditional" is doing. It seems to use pointers and /or lists which I am not comfortable with but which could be interesting if this is really equivalent to my "Russian dolls" ternary condition. When I read your last lines, I feel like the code is returning a 0 or a 1 and that is it.

Comment: @Amentia "variadic conditional" is just what i call the function you want to write. If I understood correctly you wanted to write a function that can handle a variable number amount of parameters. Sorry for just putting the code without much explanation... those are iterators, not pointers. `x.begin()` is an iterator to the first element in the vector and `*x.begin()` is then a reference to the first element in the vector

Comment: @Amentia " I feel like the code is returning a 0 or a 1 and that is it" ... maybe I misunderstood your quesiton completely, but I understood your ternary `boolean = a ? b : (c ? d : (e ? f : (g ? i : j );` as begin supposed to return either `true` or `false`

Comment: But in my case each condition matter because both true and false statements are used to create the steps, the conditions being intervals that are following each other like a<x<b => we take z>0 then if we are not in this interval, we go to b<x<c => we take z>1 and so on. This ternary thing combined with a recursive call to make as many intervals as I want was the only idea I could come up with because I did it for a simple case with only a few intervals and I saw the steps with a visualisation tool. But if the generalisation has to use a different way of thinking, I am really willing to listen.

Comment: @Amentia the actual use case is not really clear. I have the feeling that already `boolean = a ? b : (c ? d : (e ? f : (g ? i : j );` is not really what you need for checking those several conditions. Anyhow, `my_conditional({ b< x && x < c, true, z>1, true, false});` would return `true` if both conditions are `true` and `false` otherwise

Comment: I may not have been clear but the purpose is to create a geometrical shape that we can visualise and not just ask for a point if it is inside. We must ask for all the points and then keep all the one for which the conditions are true. I don't know if I could draw something similar to what I want and if we can upload images on this website.

Comment: @Amentia well maybe just stick with the other answer if I didnt manage to make myself clear. The code is just to demnostrate how you *could* write such a function, but I am suggesting not to do so. Use plain `if-else` instead. Maybe ill try to improve the answer, or maybe just delete it ;)

Comment: please do not delete your answer, it could be useful even as it is now, it is necessary to look at different explanations and ways of thinking to solve a problem. I don't know if this is understandable but when I wrote: steps = ((x >=q && x<b) ? z>0 :
           (x >=b && x<c) ?  z>=1 :
           (x >=c && x<d) ?  zprime>=2:
           (x>d) ?  zprime>=2 :  zprime>=2);
it really made little steps as I wanted. And I could not see how to translate that even with if...else statement that are supposed to be equivalent because then I want to continue with many line, like for loop, recursion...